# "We merely skimmed the surface of the cities." Does this make sense?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Does that make sense to describe how our travel was rushed therefore couldn't fully enjoy what the cities have to offer?

Comment: Not really.  We merely got a glimpse of all the cities had to offer.

Comment: Right. Instead of "sightsee", we now have "sight glimpse"...

Comment: Not as idiomatic as it would be standalone: 'We spent a couple of days in each of Paris, Berlin, Vienna and Budapest, which was nowhere near enough to do these wonderful cities justice – we merely skimmed the surface.' This is probably because 'skimmed the surface of Paris' doesn't distance the metaphor's vehicle from the tenor sufficiently to avoid the temptation to envisage ludicrous incongruities.

Comment: "We barely/merely skimmed the cities."?

Answer (score 1):

It is an idiomatic use that is reliably understood in the manner you suggest: that you only had time to see or feel a few aspects of the cities.

> Skim = to read or look at something quickly to understand the main points, without studying it in detail:

Several dictionaries of idiom show “skim the surface” as something like:

> skim the surface (of something)
>
> To do, engage with, or understand something to only a minimal or superficial degree.
>
> [Free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/skimming+the+surface+of)